# Handle multiple Http request using RxjS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a scenario where I want to first make an HTTP call, and when the response(1) comes I want to make second HTTP call which does not need the response(1), and suppose this second HTTP call gives response(2). Now I want to make multple HTTP calls that would be using data from both response(1) and response(2). How can I acheive this Using RxJS?

Comment: If the 2nd call doesn't depend on the response from the 1st call, why does it have to be made after the 1st call responds? Couldn't 1st and 2nd call be made in parallel?

Comment: Its just that if first call didn't gave response or it gave some error then we don't want to make second api call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the `concatMap` operator plus some tricks to move the response of the first call down to the last calls.

So the code could look like this

```
firstCall().pipe(
   // use concatMap to make sure you make the second call after the first one completes
   concatMap(resp_1 => {
      return secondCall().pipe(
         // use map here to move both the first and second response down the pipeline
         map(resp_2 => {
           // here we place both responses into an object which is returned by map
           return {resp_1, resp_2}
         })
      ),
      // now it is time to make all other calls once the second call has completed
      // therefore again we use concatMap
      concatMap(({resp_1, resp_2}) => {
         // the function passed to concatMap has to return an Observable
         // I assume these calls can be made in parallel and so I use forkJoin
         // which returns an Observable which notifies as soon as all the 
         // calls have completed
         return forkJoin([thirdCall({resp_1, resp_2}), fourthCall({resp_1, resp_2}), ...])
      })
   })
)
// here you subscribe
.subscribe({
   next: arrayOfResponses => {
      // do something with the array of responses of thirdCall, fourthCall and so on
   }
})
```

You may find [this article interesting](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) as it talks about common patterns of use of RxJs with http calls